# Can each new click produce a new image?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I know how to make an image  appear using onclick or  onMouseOver but how can I make each click produce the appropriate image not just in the same place but, for example, in a row, next to it's previous apperance? My idea is this: I click on reference1 and a picture1 shows up. Then I click on reference2 and a picture2 shows up next to the picture1 already displayed. Now I click on reference1 again, and I want to see pictures 1,2,1 in a row. How can I do that? My ideal would be to see the row rolling when filled, and a delete button deleting the last image in that row, even making the pictures jump out being called from the text field, but I can search for these myself. My greatest concern for now is new click=new image. Thank you.

Comment: What language? Also, consider tagging your question with the correct language-specific tag; it will get faster attention that way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is relatively simplistic- you could keep track of the current position in a list of images, afterwards create a function that deals with the current image then increments this position. Have the onClick event call this function, and there you are.

An example of this in action, using JQuery, can be viewed here:
http://jsfiddle.net/8Q4LQ/

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .refimg { width: 100px; height: 100px; }
      .choices a { margin-right: 2ex; }
      .choices img { display: none; }
      #target { display:block; width: 500px; overflow-x: scroll; border: 1px solid black; }
    </style>
  </head>
<body>
  Choices:
  <div class="choices">
    <a href="#" onclick="return putImage(image1);">ref1</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="return putImage(image2);">ref2</a>
    <image id="image1" src="image1.gif" class="refimg" />
    <image id="image2" src="image2.gif" class="refimg" />
  </div>
  <br />
  Selections: <input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="delImage()" />
  <nobr id="target">
  </nobr>

  <script>
  function putImage(src) {
    var a = src.cloneNode(true);
    a.id = ''; //clear id to prevent duplicate id
    target.appendChild(a);
    a.scrollIntoView(true);
    return false;
  }
  function delImage() {
    var a=target.children;
    if (a.length>0) target.removeChild(a[a.length-1]);
  }
  target.style.height=((target.offsetHeight-target.clientHeight)+100)+'px'; //extend height for scroll bar
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```